# Partial Functions as an input parameter in scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to pass the partial function as input to square function. 
   What is worng with the following code?

```
package PartialFunction

object PartialFunctionSum {
  val yourConstant = 10

  val pf: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) => x + y + yourConstant
  }
  def square(cb:(Int, Int) => Int): Unit = {
     println(cb(5,10))
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit= {
   square(pf)
  }  
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Or does it work, but not as you expected? Please describe the problem for which your are seeking help.

Answer (score 2):

A PartialFunction is a `Function1` (a => b) and `square` needs a `Function2` ((a,b) => c)

One way to accomplish what you want to do is changing `cb` type to `Function1`.

```
object PartialFunctionSum extends App {

  val yourConstant = 10

  val pf: PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int] = {
    case (x, y) => x + y + yourConstant
  }
  def square(cb:((Int, Int)) => Int): Unit = {
    println(cb(5,10))
  }

  square(pf)

}
```

Also, anywhere where you need a `FunctionX`, you can define a `PartialFunction`, so

```
square {
  case (x, y) => x + y + yourConstant
}
```

Or transform your PartialFunction in a Function2 with a lambda

```
square( pf.apply(_, _) )
```

Comment: More precisely, the case block will be taken as a Function or PartialFunction as required. ("Pattern-matching anonymous function".) So there's no PF in `square { case ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you need a function you can a pass a PartialFunction,

Your problem is with square definition:

```
def square(cb:(Int, Int) => Int): Unit = {
    println(cb(5,10))
}
```

That means that cb is a function that receives two Ints and returns another Int.

Just change square signature as follows:

```
def square(cb: ((Int, Int)) => Int): Unit = {
  println(cb(5 -> 10))
}
```

And now your types are compatible and the rest of your code works as you expected.

Answer (score 0):

`(Int, Int) => Int` is an instance of `Function2[Int, Int, Int]`(a Function that takes 2 `Int` parameters and returns an `Int`), not `PartialFunction[(Int, Int), Int]` (a partial function that takes an input of type `(Int, Int)` and returns an `Int`)

If you want to pass your parameters as a Tuple then:

```
def square(cb:PartialFunction[(Int, Int),Int]): Unit = {
     println(cb((5,10)))
  }
```

Example:

```
def square(cb:PartialFunction[(Int, Int),Int]): Unit = {
     println(cb((5,10)))
  }

square: (cb: PartialFunction[(Int, Int),Int])Unit

scala> square{case (i, j) => i * j}
50
```